# WDT reset cause 4 after reinstalling Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, adafruit, neopixel

I try to control my LED strip with an Android app.
I reinstalled the Arduino IDE since I didn't like the Windows-store version. The serial monitor broke for whatever reason so I switched back to the Windows-store version.

But now I'm getting a WDT reset error, which I can't seem to overcome.

I'm also using Adafruit_NeoPixel and wherever I put "ledstrip.begin" or "ledstrip.show" seems to break it.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

byte RED = 14;
byte GREEN = 12;
byte BLUE = 13;
byte PIN_COUNT = 20;
Adafruit_NeoPixel ledstrip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(PIN_COUNT, 6, NEO_RGB + NEO_KHZ800); //(num of leds, )
WiFiServer server(port);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);
    ledstrip.begin();        

    Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    byte tries;
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        tries++;
        Serial.println(".");
        if (tries == 5)
        {
            Serial.println("Connection failed");
            return;
        }
    }
    Serial.println("\nWiFi connected");

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Server URL: ");
    Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
}
void print_tokens(char* strings)
{   
    byte index = sizeof(strings);
    for (int n = 0; n < index; n++)
    {
        Serial.println(strings[n]);
    }
}

char *tokenize_request(String request)
{
    char requestArray[1024];
    char *ptr = NULL;
    byte index = 0;
    char *strings[10];

    strcpy(requestArray, request.c_str());
    ptr = strtok(requestArray, ";");

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        strings[index] = ptr;
        index++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
    return *strings;
}

void loop()
{
    WiFiClient responder = server.available();
    if (!responder)
    {
        return;
    }
    while (!responder.available())
    {
        delay(1);
    }

    String request = responder.readStringUntil('@');
    char *strings[10] = {tokenize_request(request)};

    print_tokens(*strings);

    int mode = atoi(strings[0]);
    int R = atoi(strings[1]);
    int G = atoi(strings[2]);
    int B = atoi(strings[3]);

    if (mode == 1)
    {
        ledstrip.setPixelColor(5, R, G, B);
    }

    if (mode == 0)
    {
        ledstrip.setPixelColor(5, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    ledstrip.show();
    delay(1);
    Serial.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Serial monitor output:

[image: Serial Monitor Output]

Comment: part of the startup script for the IDE contains a command to disable the WDT.   My suspicion is the startup script is not being activated.

Comment: How can i reactivate it?

Comment: in function: `setup()`  there is this variable declaration: `byte tries;`    Then in a following loop there is: `tries++;`   However, the variable `tries` is never initialized (preferably to 0)  This results in undefined behavior

Comment: in function: `print_tokens()`  there is this statement: `byte index = sizeof(strings);` which will yield the number of bytes in a pointer.  Not the number of entities or bytes in the passed in array of char pointers

Comment: in the function: `tokenize_request()`, the array of pointers to string is declared to have size of 10 elements.  Strongly suggest declaring that array to be all NULL values.  Strongly suggest the 10 be the value of a `#define SOMETHING 10` rather than a 'magic' number.  Then use that `SOMETHING` as the limit of the loop in the function: `print_tokens()`

Comment: in the function: `print_tokens()`, the loop will be going around (after other corrections) 10 times.  (and as the code is, printing some garbage values unless the `readStringUntil()` results in exactly 10 tokens.  With the `#define` and the NULL initializtion of `strings[]`, then the loop in `print_tokens()` can look for either a NULL entry and no more than SOMETHING iterations.  This would go a long way toward not printing trash

Comment: regarding: `char *strings[10] = {tokenize_request(request)};`  Why the braces around the call to `tokenize_request()`?

Comment: The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  to expose the prototype for the function: `atoi()`

Comment: The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` to expose the prototype for the function: `strtok()`

Comment: in function; `tokenize_request()`, it is returning a pointer to a local (on the stack) array of pointers.  However, that array goes 'out of scope' when the function exits.  The result is undefined behavior.  Suggest either declare the array with `file scope` or use 'malloc()` to allocate the memory.  (be sure to call `free()` when done with that array)

Comment: Thanks for all the help and advice! I will try to optimize it. 
But i think the error is at the beginning. The first thing it should print in the setupt is "Connecting to: " but it doesnt even get there. 
It gets stuck at "ledstrip.begin();"

Comment: Probably the 'gets stuck' is what allows the watchdog timer (wdt) to time out and reset the computer

Comment: Don't add "fixed" to the question. And if the problem was hardware, then the question was non-reproducible and therefore should be closed. But your code has a lot of actual problems that were already addressed.

Comment: How can i let others know how i fixed my problem if they encounter the same problem?

Comment: The problem is caused by code. Pin 6 is just an output and shouldn't have any affect on code execution. `ledstrip.begin();` just sets the pin as an output and sets it low. There is nothing to get stuck. It doesn't matter if anything is connected to it.